# Eclipse Buildpath can't find .class files from jar

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, buildpath

I've got this project that depends on a jar that contains the sources and class files(an entire Eclipse Java project).  Without it, I have errors because it can't find the correct imports.  Soon as I add the jar to the build path of my project, those errors go away.  So it's certainly finding the stuff it needs before runtime.

The problem is, when I go to run the application...it can't find the correct class to load at runtime.  What else do I need to do in order for it to find the correct classes?

Comment: How do you run the application? What is the exact and complete error message you get? I hope you realize that the jar is also needed at runtime, in the classpath.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: models/environments/Environment.  On the build path I have Maven, JRE, and the jar. It shows in my .classpath file an entry like:  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/MyJar.jar"/>

Comment: Found the source of the error by sidestepping a bit.  Added the project instead of the jar to the build path and everything works smoothly. Apparently the project has a configured build path that points to further libs and those cannot be detected in a jar.  Not sure how to setup that recursive dependency with a jar.

Answer (score 0):

In Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries, point to Classpath, then "Add External Jars", put the jar file, then Apply.
Now you can run your application.